# Is it true that $ n\sqrt{n^2-1} > \frac{n^2}{2}?$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is it true?

$$ n\sqrt{n^2-1} > \frac{n^2}{2}$$

Even if $ n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$ this should be obviously true.  Note that $\sqrt{n^2-1}$ acts very similarly to $\sqrt{n^2}$ which simplifies to $n$., so the expression on the left acts like $n^2$ while the expression on the right acts like $\frac{n^2}{2}$.  As for proof., consider an intermediate expression:  $n\cdot \sqrt{n^2-\frac{3}{4}n^2}$ and how that compares to both.

Comment: @JMoravitz I had the same thinking path as you. However, even if n goes to infinity it will hold?

Comment: Oh, thank you @JMoravitz

Comment: Let me rephrase a bit more precisely... Yes, for all sufficiently large real numbers (*or all sufficiently large natural numbers*) the expression on the left will be larger than the expression on the right, regardless of how large it is.  The limits of each expression will be infinite.  Infinity is not a number that we would consider plugging into such an expression and so is irrelevant otherwise.

Comment: That being said, the question of whether it works for *all* possible values of $n$... try a few small simple examples.  Is it true for $n=0$?  Is it true for $n=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use that
$$
\sqrt{1-\frac1{n^2}}> \frac12,\qquad n\ge2,
$$ giving, by multiplying by $n^2$,
$$
n^2\sqrt{1-\frac1{n^2}}=n\sqrt{n^2-1}> \frac{n^2}2,\qquad n\ge2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $n > 0$, if $\sqrt{n^2-1} \in \mathbb{R}$ we must have $n\ge 1$. Assuming that, we divide both sides by $n$ to get
$$
\sqrt{n^2-1} > n/2
$$
which is equivalent to (since $n>1$)
$$
n^2-1 > n^2/4
$$
which is equivalent to $$n > \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\approx 1.1547.$$

We conclude that as long as $n>1.1547$, your inequality holds.

Comment: $0$ is not larger than $\frac{1}{2}$.  It fails for $n=1$

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry fixed thanks

Comment: This confuses implications and equivalences, and should be rewritten more rigorously.

Comment: @Did please check now

Answer (score 0):

$$n\sqrt{n^2-1}=n^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
Using series expression at '$n=\infty$' we get that
$$n^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}=n^2\left(1-\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{8n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\right)$$
$$=n^2-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
So it's bigger than $\frac{n^2}{2}$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 0):

As shown above by "gt6989b", $n>1.15$

Suppose $n>1.8, n^2>2$ Then $n^2-2>0$

$n^2-2>0$

$(n^2-1)-1>0$

$3(n^2-1)-1>0$

$3n^2-3-1>0$

$3n^2-4>0$

$3n^2+n^2-4>n^2$

$4n^2-4>n^2$

$n^2-1>\frac{n^2}{4}$

$\sqrt{n^2-1}>\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{4}}$

$\sqrt{n^2-1}>\frac{n}{2}$  or  $n\sqrt{n^2-1}>\frac{n^2}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "even if", $n \to \infty$.  I'd say "*especially* if" $n \to \infty$.

If $n>2$ then $n^2 > 2n > 2$ and $n\sqrt{n^2 - 1} = $

$n\sqrt{n^2 - 2+1} > n\sqrt{n^2 - 2n + 1} = $

$n\sqrt{(n-1)^2}= n(n-1)=$

$n^2 - n > n^2 - \frac {n^2}2 = \frac {n^2}2$

And that's it....

It is true if $n> 2$.  Period.

I suppose you're thinking is that if $n\to \infty$ is somehow equivalent to $n = \infty$ and if $n$ is infinity than both expressions are infinite and we can't have one infinite value *greater* than another value.

But that not what $n\to \infty$ means.  Infinity is not a number that we can plug into $n$.  $n \to \infty$ simply means that $n$ may be as arbitrarily large as we like.

If "$n$ approaches $\infty$" that means we may assume $n > 2$ so this it true. Notice if $1\le n <\frac {2\sqrt{3}}3$ or $n\le -1$   then $n\sqrt{n^2 - 1} < \frac {n^2}2$

Comment: My thinking was exactly what you have thought. The notion of infinity confuses repetitively but you postpone it